# Syncing updates to master in master/slave setup [semi-sync replication]

Tags: mysql, semi-sync-replication

### Background info

I have two MySQL 5.5 servers set up in a Master/Slave configuration with **Semi-synchronous** replication.

The database is being used for a high-profile WordPress site.

### Problem

It seems to work great except for one thing:

When the master is down and changes are made to the slave, they are not written back to the master when it comes back up.

### What I've done so far

I tried the answer [[here]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2733/how-do-you-re-sync-the-master-mysql-db-with-slave-db-changes-if-the-master-goes), but it broke my replication completely.

### Questions

- Is there a more standard way of setting this up or is it generally not supported?
- Should I just disallow writes on the slave?
- Is there a simple way to notify the master of changes, and sync them upstream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. I guess you have missed the `auto_increment_increment` & `auto_increment_offset` variables.

Set `auto increment increment` to the total number of servers.

Set `auto_increment_offset` to a number between 1 and `auto increment increment` for each server.

example:

Server 1: `auto increment increment` = 2, `auto_increment_offset` = 1

Server 2: `auto increment increment` = 2, `auto_increment_offset` = 2

Comment: I believe this helped... I'm still not sure. I ended up making both servers primary, with the above commands also, and now my config works.